# how place large sized footer div below small sized main-container div

Tags: html, css, header, containers, footer

I have the header and main-container div having width 1000px and are relatively positioned. below that I need a footer of width 1300px but if i position it relative it becomes 1000px and if i position it fixed it is not centered just below the main-container. Hope you get my Q.
code details are:

```
.main-header {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    max-width: 1000px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    min-height:145px;
    border-bottom:none;
}
.main-container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);
}

.copyrights {
    float:left;
    width:1300px;
    height:285px;
    clear: both;
    background: #7e8285;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color: #d3d4d6;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    position: relative;
    border-top:none;
    z-index:1;
}
```

/*copyrights is a class defined for footer area.*/
I want header,main-container 1000px in width and footer 1300px in width.

Comment: please post all relevant code to your question (html)

Comment: I am not even sure what is being asked and what's the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your body style as 1300px. That sounds like the problem. I just coded and it works perfectly for me.

```
body {
    width: 1300px;
}

.main-header {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    min-height: 145px;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #F70B0F;
}
.main-container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1532B5;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);
}

.copyrights {
    float: left;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 285px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #ACD2EF;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #d3d4d6;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: hi, actually it was a stylesheet code in one of the wordpress themes. after thoroughly studying I got that main-container is a wrapper class,within that there were header and footers. but main problem was main containers width initially defined 1000px and since footer was a part of main container it was not possible to add 1300px width footer inside 1000px width main-container. which was what i needed.

Comment: Yeah. That is what I thought. So, you just ended up increasing the containers width to allow for a larger footer like I suggested? Glad you figured it out. Could you plus one my answer so that I can get my reputation up?